# Handle all http errors in the same way

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling, ionic2

All calls to my api are made through a service I created with the "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH" methods. If any of these calls fail I would like to show the error in an alert and if the error status is 401 redirect the user to the login. How can I make a generic error handler?

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import lodash from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  url: string = 'https://leetags-api.herokuapp.com';
  options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
    withCredentials: true
  });

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(endpoint: string, params?: any, options: RequestOptionsArgs = {}): Observable<Response> {
    if (params) {
      const urlSearchParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      lodash.forEach(params, (value: any, key: string): void => urlSearchParams.set(key, value));
      options.search = !options.search ? urlSearchParams : options.search;
    }

    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${endpoint}`, this.options.merge(options));
  }

  post(endpoint: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${endpoint}`, body, this.options.merge(options));
  }

  put(endpoint: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${endpoint}`, body, this.options.merge(options));
  }

  delete(endpoint: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${endpoint}`, this.options.merge(options));
  }

  patch(endpoint: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${endpoint}`, body, this.options.merge(options));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make a `catch()` method in your service and assign it to the catch handler of your `http` call. The `.catch` block is automatically called whenever a api call fails.

Your above `http` statement should then look like following (for `GET`):

```
get() {
        return this._http.get(this.getUserUrl)
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.myCatchFunction);
    }

myCatchFunction(error: Response){
 //look here for specific codes present in response error and handle accordingly
}
```

Hope this helps